# Odd Ruby output lag under nohup?

Tags: ruby, linux, nohup

I'm seeing some confusing behavior with a Ruby script while running under `nohup`. Basically I'm doing this:

```
require 'logger'

logger_file = open('/mnt/dbsdata/output.log', File::WRONLY | File::APPEND | File::CREAT)
LOGGER = Logger.new(logger_file)
LOGGER.level = Logger::INFO

  def run_command(cmd,display=true)
    if display
      LOGGER.info "Executing: #{cmd}"
    end
    output = `#{cmd} 2>&1` ; results=$?.success?
    if ! results
        LOGGER.error "FAILED to execute #{cmd}"
        LOGGER.error output
        return false
    end
    return true
  end

begin
  run_command("some_longrunning_command", true)
  run_command("some_other_longrunning_command",true)
  # etc...
end
```

What's weird here is that both when using Logger as above, and just normal `puts` to STDOUT (nohup.out), the output timing is way off. I'd think I could just tail the logfile and see real time logging messages (log message, execute command, repeat), however what's happening is a bulk flush of messages to log of many stale messages all at once, long after their command was already executed and completed.

When executing the script like so from the shell:

```
`nohup ruby myscript.rb &`
```

This behaves as expected when not run under nohup.

Anyone experienced this and know a good workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't say for sure, but it sounds like an IO `sync` issue. I/O is generally buffered for speed. RAM is a lot faster than disks, so reads and writes are temporarily stored until the data is requested by the code, or the disk is able to receive it. Ruby's IO class has the `sync=` method that lets you tell Ruby to immediately flush the buffer on a write.

This should work:

```
logger_file = open('/mnt/dbsdata/output.log', File::WRONLY | File::APPEND | File::CREAT)
logger_file.sync = true
LOGGER = Logger.new(logger_file)
LOGGER.level = Logger::INFO
```

For simplicity, you can create the correct mode you want for your output using:

```
    logger_file = File.open('/mnt/dbsdata/output.log', 'a')
```

Comment: Excellent, that's a winner. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Just as a caveat: Don't force sync unless absolutely necessary, such as when you're writing to a log or using Logger. For normal I/O, let Ruby buffer it. Your CPU and code-speed will thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The logging is not excessively frequent nor verbose, so I'm not seeing too much of a performance hit in this case. As stated, this issue only occurs while the script is under nohup -- and not only with the logger, with normal stdout too. If you're aware of any resources that might explain that, I'd appreciate a link. Otherwise, I can also consider daemonizing too. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm not a fan of daemonizing, because it's hard to debug, set-up, etc. `nohup` is somewhat of a poor-man's daemonize, but it's a LOT easier to debug. You might ask on http://superuser.com about this, that's the sibling site for system administrators, who'd know a lot more about what could cause this problem. Good luck!

Comment: Instead of using STDOUT.sync = true you can call `STDOUT.flush` at the points you want to flush output.  This gives you better control over when to have the buffer flush, and which specific buffer.  You are still at the mercy of the OS though, at least for MRI.

Comment: The OP is not using STDOUT, so using `sync` or `flush` on that channel won't help. The `sync` has to occur on the filehandle that is open and then passed to Logger.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like buffering.  Try logging to stderr and see if that helps.